# Extend Onepage Billing block in Magento

Tags: magento, overriding, extend, billing

I hope someone already knows how solve this as I've been trying for a couple of days, followed countless tutorials and sadly not got far.

I am attempting to override the block file : /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Billing.php in a custom module (for Magento 1.7)

in my module config.xml file, I have added the following:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_billing>
                    Jrc_GiftListShipping_Block_Onepage_Billing
                </onepage_billing>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

and created a file in the following location:

/app/code/local/Jrc/GiftListShipping/Block/Onepage/Billing.php
which contains the following simple code:

```
<?php
Class Jrc_GiftListShipping_Block_Onepage_Billing extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

However the above generates an exception:

`exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: 
                        Jrc_GiftListShipping_Block_Onepage_Billing`

I can't see anything wrong with the code above but I really hope someone else can and educate me a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<onepage_billing>Jrc_GiftListShipping_Block_Onepage_Billing</onepage_billing>
```

Don't use reformat code for xml in magento

Comment: @zhartaunik: I've got the same issue but that is already one line for me. Im running 1.9.0.1 and the error says as well `Invalid block type` do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Declare that your module's block so that the autoloader can find your block classes:

```
<blocks>
    <giftlistshipping>
        <class>Jrc_GiftListShipping_Block</class>
    </giftlistshipping>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <onepage_billing>
                Jrc_GiftListShipping_Block_Onepage_Billing
            </onepage_billing>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```

Comment: This is most common mistake. When you call reformat code - your IDE or some another system put value and tags in different rows. Magento doesn't allow that

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the same but the confix file was already like the approved answer here. After 10 hours I finally found the solution, compilation was active which prevented Magento from finding the new files.

`System->Tool->compilation`

**Deactivate this.**

Also if applicable check if caching is on. This could cause the similar issue.